# Having trouble understanding tree traversal recursive functions

Tags: recursion, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, preorder

I am having some trouble understanding the recursive functions involved in preorder, inorder, and postorder tree traversal. I have some knowledge of recursion (but admittedly its not my strong suit). All of the seem to call themselves twice first making a call with the left child of the root and then with the right child. But how exactly is this possible? Wouldn't the call to the preOrder function with the left child return the flow of control back to the top, and the next call would never be executed?

```
void preOrder (Node* root) 
{
    if (root == NULL) return;
    cout<<root->val<<", ";
    preOrder(root->left);
    preOrder(root->right);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Wouldn't the call to the preOrder function with the left child return the flow of control back to the top, and the next call would never be executed?*

Of course not. The recursive call works just like any other function call: after the function completion the control returns to the place of call. 'The place' means not only the point in the code but also the point on the call stack, which means the same set of variables is available again. Just like after returning from any other function.

For example if you have a tree

```
        A
       / \
      X   Y
```

and you call `preorder` on the `A` node, then it first prints the `A` contents, then calls `preorder` on `X` and on return it is back in `preorder(A)`, so it proceeds to call `preorder` on `Y`.

Answer (score 1):

**Preorder**: Process the node, move to the left child, move to the right child

```
void preorder(Node *root)
{
    if (root == NULL) //<- Check if the currently passed node is empty
        return; //<- if it is, return from the function back down the stack

    cout << root->val << ", "; //<- if it wasn't empty, print its value

    if (root->left != NULL) //<- check if the node to the left is empty
        preorder(root->left); //<- if not recurse to the left child

    if (root->right != NULL) //<- check if the node to the right is empty
        preorder(root->right); //<- if not recurse to the right child
}
```

**Inorder**: move to the left, process the node, move to the right

```
void inorder(Node *root)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return;

    if (root->left != NULL) //<- check if the node to the left is empty
            inorder(root->left); //<- if not recurse to the left child

    cout << root->val << ", ";

    if (root->right != NULL) //<- check if the node to the right is empty
            inorder(root->right); //<- if not recurse to the right child
}
```

**Postorder**: Move to the left node, move to the right node, process the node

```
void postorder(Node *root)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return;

    if (root->left != NULL) //<- check if the node to the left is empty
            postorder(root->left); //<- if not recurse to the left child

    if (root->right != NULL) //<- check if the node to the right is empty
            postorder(root->right); //<- if not recurse to the right child

    cout << root->val << ", "
}
```

Comment: 1. Don't call an arbitrary node a `root`. 2. If you test *inside* a function for an argument being `NULL` then you don't have to test it *before* recursive call on `left` and `right` pointers. Of course that saves you void calls on non-existent leafs' children, but OTOH it adds the testing overhead on all internal nodes.

Comment: @CiaPan the null testing for the node to simply return if for the possibility the the origin root may be empty.

Comment: I know what is it for. I just pointed out that testing `if(node->left)` before `postorder(node->left)` is superfluous, because the function will test it again after the call.

Answer (score 0):

```
void preorder(node *p) {
   if(p) {
     cout << p->val <<"\n";
     preorder(p->left);
     preorder(p->right);
   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is looking for an *explanation*, not simply for working code.  Your answer provides no insight for the questioner, and may be deleted.  Please [edit] to explain what causes the observed symptoms.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.