# I cannot step through the logic! Can someone point me in the correct direction?

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7

Can anyone help me step through the logic of the program shown below? I tried using the [Python debugger](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html). This did not help me that much though.

I do not understand the following:

- `preorder_traversal()`

  - For instance at the `yield (parent, root)` line of code; does the function return these values as a generator at this point to the caller or does it return the generator and then keep going inside the `preorder_traversal()` function?
  - Also, mind completely melts when trying to wrap my head around the **recursive call** to `preorder_traversal()`. Does anyone know of a way to understand this? Like a truth table or something like that that I can use to manually step through the program with a pen and paper or notepad or whatever. I think the most complicated part of this is the nesting and the recursion.
- I do not understand the Node inside a Node inside a Node, etc. Or the whole adding and edge part which adds a Node to a list.

## Code

```
class Node(object):
    """A simple digraph where each node knows about the other nodes
    it leads to.
    """
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.connections = []
        return

    def add_edge(self, node):
        "Create an edge between this node and the other."
        self.connections.append(node)
        return

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.connections)

def preorder_traversal(root, seen=None, parent=None):
    """Generator function to yield the edges via a preorder traversal."""
    if seen is None:
        seen = set()
    yield (parent, root)
    if root in seen:
        return
    seen.add(root)
    for node in root:
        for (parent, subnode) in preorder_traversal(node, seen, root):
            yield (parent, subnode)
    return

def show_edges(root):
    "Print all of the edges in the graph."
    for parent, child in preorder_traversal(root):
        if not parent:
            continue
        print '%5s -> %2s (%s)' % (parent.name, child.name, id(child))

# Set up the nodes.
root = Node('root')
a = Node('a')
b = Node('b')
c = Node('c')

# Add edges between them.
root.add_edge(a)
root.add_edge(b)
a.add_edge(b)
b.add_edge(a)
b.add_edge(c)
a.add_edge(a)

print 'ORIGINAL GRAPH:'
show_edges(root)
```

Thank-you for reading this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the "yield" keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do)

Comment: What about the recursive algorithm confusion part?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Having trouble understanding tree traversal recursive functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33818795/having-trouble-understanding-tree-traversal-recursive-functions)

Answer (score 1):

As for the [`yield`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) operator, `yield` allows the function to be a generator, thus [lazy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation).  For this particular example, the need for a generator is not needed and its only benefit is much better readability (i.e. `for _ in _`). Abstractly, `yield (parent, root)` is returned by using the [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) operation on the generator. Then, when `next()` is called again, the generator continues to dynamically execute the remaining code in the function.

As for the recursive call, this is fairly common when doing any type of [graph traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal). Furthermore, a graph is a [recursive data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_data_type).

[Here](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/) is a good resource for understanding graph traversals.

Below is a slightly modified version of the `preorder_traversal()` (easier to read) which has some comments:

```
def preorder_traversal(root, seen=set(), parent=None):
    """Generator function to yield the edges via a preorder traversal."""
    yield (parent, root)

    # avoid cycle
    if root not in seen:
        seen.add(root)

        # for each neighbor of the root
        for node in root:

            # for each (parent, neighbor) pair in the subgraph 
            # not containing the nodes already seen 
            for (parent, subnode) in preorder_traversal(node, seen, root):
                yield (parent, subnode)
```

To demonstrate the lazy nature of a Python generator, consider the custom `irange()` generator where `irange(n) == xrange(n+1)`:

```
def irange(limit):
    current_number = 0
    while current_number <= limit:
        yield current_number
        current_number += 1
```

If you do `a = irange(9999999999999999999999)`, no code in `irange()` is performed until `next()` is called on it.

To understand recursion with generators, consider the custom `rrange()` generator where `rrange(n) == reversed(irange(n))`:

```
def rrange(limit):
    if limit >= 0:
        yield limit
        for num in rrange(limit - 1):
            yield num
```